# Como não retornar um valor "X" no BD?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Como faço pra não retornar um valor "X" no banco de dados?
Por exemplo, eu tenho um site estilo Vagalume, e o mesmo tem a página de cada artista onde se encontra a aba "Artistas Relacionados" que é com base nas TAG's cadastradas no BD, queria que não retornasse o valor do artista da página atual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edita o post com o código a explicar melhor a dúvida por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderá fazer de 2 formas:

**Simples, filtrando 1 registro:**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tb_artistas WHERE id <> $id';
```

*Exemplo do resultado esperado da query:*

```
SELECT * FROM tb_artistas WHERE id <> 27
```

ou caso traga mais de 1 registro, separando por vírgula:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tb_artistas WHERE id NOT IN ($ids)';
```

*Exemplo do resultado esperado da query:*

```
SELECT * FROM tb_artistas WHERE id NOT IN (25,84,64,86)
```

---

**Filtrando vários registros, para uma pesquisa mais formulada (por exemplo, com TAG):**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tb_artistas WHERE id <> $id AND tag IN (tags)';
```

*Exemplo do resultado esperado da query:*

```
SELECT * FROM tb_artistas WHERE id <> $id AND tag IN (2,5,8,10)
```

Answer (score 5):

Se você se refere ao SQL, basta usar por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_artistas WHERE id_artista <> id_artista_atual
```